# Concerns as I start a new job

Tags: new-job, career-development

I know in this economy one should be grateful for having a job (and maybe I am being a bit entitled here), but please hear me out. I got laid off in June and was interviewing pretty much all summer for a new opportunity. I finally found an opportunity with a company but when it came time to extending an offer the internal recruiter presented an offer which was 45% below what I had made with my previous employer and had explicitly told me that "they're bringing you in at a lower level than discussed". I told her no, but if she could increase I'd consider it. She came back and said that they can bring me in at a salary 25% less than what I had made with my previous employer and that there would be a process to get this approved (and that since this will take work this will be the best they can offer and how they're going out of their way for me). Desperate for a job during the pandemic I accepted. Also, it was understood that I would move to a location with a lower cost of living (and no state taxes), but they also reneged on this as well (and told me I would have to stay put - presumably since it would cost them to relocate me). I also found out that she either didn't know or wasn't completely truthful with me about the company not doing any relocations since I found out that people had been relocated during the pandemic.

I ended up taking this offer and when I joined I connected with a few colleagues at this company from college, my previous job, personal life. What really bothers me is that some of my colleagues from my previous job had been given offers at their previous rate and were bought in at a level higher than I was (the level I had initially interviewed for) - even for some of my colleagues who were somewhat junior than me at my old job. Additionally, I've come to realize the people on my team who are at the same level as I are essentially 4-5 years out of school whereas I have 10 years of experience.

Lastly, I am noticing that what they are having me do is take over for someone who has been doing the work manually (so having me automate processes) - but someone who has been working 15+ hour days and who really never sleeps - and service 5+ PMs. This possibly means that in order to survive and flourish I will have to work insane hours doing the work of 3/4 people and with people in this role typically not promoted even after working for many years. So they are essentially wanting senior level production from me while I am being recognized at a junior level and at a discount. Promotions typically don't happen for many years and the recruiter stated that in 2022 they will review my 2021 performance to see whether they want to promote and potentially true up my salary to what I had made previously - which I'm sure they say to everyone to get them excited. Mind you my current salary is what I had made back in 2017 when I lived in a cheap mid-atlantic east coast city.

I feel like I've been hoodwinked and am thoroughly unhappy. Or maybe this is just the nature of the pandemic where its a buyer's market and employers can "dictate terms in their favor". This is definitely not the way I had wanted to start out with a new job, but I feel like I had to take it since I had been looking for a while (but then again - I shouldn't complain since I did accept the job at the end of the day and it was my decision). What do you folks think and how do you guys/gals suggest I navigate this? Should I work at this job yet continue looking since I do feel like I'm not starting off on the right foot with this employer? I'm concerned that I'll be worked to the bone with no promotion/recognition to show for it since this is how they've treated me from the get go - and it makes no sense for me to work long hours to ultimately make back or get close to what I had been compensated at my previous job (which could happen in 1.5 years or 3 years - who knows??) I'm almost tempted to start my job search again, but want to hear what people think.

Comment: Are you ready to relocate and look for a new job while keeping this one? It seems like your dissatisfaction stems from the fact they lied to you about relocation (or you accepted this cross-hearted)?

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to relocate, but I definitely am ready to look while keeping this one. It's not so much about relocation as it is the level and pay - I feel like I'm not a the level and pay that I should be given my experience and what they expect from this role.

Answer (score 11):

If an employer reneges on promises and otherwise proves themselves to be dodgy, you cheerfully and professionally discharge your tasks while you job search. Anything else is asking to be let down again.

The only mitigating factor would be high remuneration, which isn't a factor here. Some people will put up with a lot for the money, but without that there is no point, it's a slippery slide.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to list yays/nays on this one.

Do you need a job to pay the bills? Yes.
Was the company truthful in the hiring? No.
Are you not being paid a age that is properly aligned with your experience? No. (And hopefully you learned NOT to discuss compensation with colleagues...)
Is the opportunity to move up there in a reasonable timeline? No.
Do you have to relocate? Not now.
Did they basically LIE about the offer? Yes.

I think you get the point... If there are positives, you didn't really list them... but I don't think there are many.

Based on your description, and not having context around the job, company, etc..., it sounds like you have landed an opportunity to help you pay the bills for now while you get to build out your resume, all while working remote.

It sounds like its a large'ish company and they are taking advantage of a job market flooded with over qualified candidates and they have no access to offshore labor. They hold the power at the moment and so can play shady games with their hires.

But again, it's a gig to pay the bills.

I would focus on the positive of learning what you can from this gig, making sure it adds something significant to YOU and to your resume. At the same time, your side hustle is going to have to be looking for the right opportunity, not the one in front of you. That's how a lot of us wind up in jobs we hate.

A good job/company doesn't love you back and in this day and age, where shareholders and invoices are more important than the team members and products that are built, you need to put yourself first. At this time, you need to take the mercenary mindset and not look for a company to solve your problems; that's not why they are there.

This doesn't sound like your forever job. But only you can answer that.

Comment: "And hopefully you learned NOT to discuss compensation with colleagues" Why not? How else are you going to find out about unfair treatment, discrimination etc.?

Comment: Knowledge is power but sometimes knowing too much will derail you. You will become more obsessed over wondering why someone is be compensated one way and that becomes your focus. It does give you data to make a point with leadership but sometimes not knowing allows for a clear mind and a better ability to focus.

Also, it could blow-back; maybe you are overly compensated and a colleague isn't? You may feel like you helped them but maybe they become discouraged and now they are derailed and you have to pick up the slack. Leadership finds out you talked and then you have to answer for it later

Comment: And one last point about the concept of unfair treatment, discrimination, etc; I feel everyone has to know what motivates them to be happy, which a lot of times comes down to personality type and your personal core values. If you feel that you can't be happy unless you are making the same amount of money at this moment as your colleagues, then that's your right. However, one could see that the long term relationships within that company could be harmed because you chose to fight on that hill of fairness as a moral value. Unfortunately, business doesn't always care about your feelings.

Answer (score 4):

Are you in a position to walk? WALK. Tell them you do not work for crooks, if you feel like it.

BUT: If you are NOT in a position to do so (which like 90% of the population are) - start looking for a new job and walk once you have it.

From what you have said, I would not want to work in that place. There are good and bad companies, but being treated like a second class citizen (compared to others moving) - nope, not my world. Now, there is NO scenario I personally would consider working there more than I need to. Unless you SERIOUSLY leave things out this sounds like an awful employer. Done.